# Solve the P.D.E. $U_x+\sqrt{U_y}=0$ where $U(x,0)=x^2+1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$U_x+\sqrt{U_y}=0$ where $U(x,0)=x^2+1$.

I tried characteristic and Lagrange methods but I’m missing something.
Anybody can give me a hint?

Comment: What is the domain? It seems that when $x>0$, then $U_x(x, 0) = 2x > 0$, so $U_x + \sqrt{U_y} > 0$. If $x<0$ you can find $U = x^2+1+4x^2y$ by inspection.

Answer (score 2):

(Ignoring the issues about when we can square the equation safely, I just focus on the method of characteristics.)

The characteristic lines for the PDE (or hypersurface in the jet manifold) $p_x^2-p_y=0$ are
$$
\dot x=p_x,\ \dot y=-1,\ \dot p_x=0,\ \dot p_y=0,\ \dot u=2p^2_x-p_y
$$
i.e., for some constants $a,b$ (satisfying $a^2=b$)
$$
x=as+x_0,\ y=y_0-s,\ p_x=a,\ p_y=b,\ u=u_0+(2a^2-b)s.
$$
Hence the solution is obtained evolving along this vector field, starting from the point
$$
\bigl(x_0,y_0=0,a=2x_0,b=4x_0^2,u_0=x_0^2+1\bigr)
$$
to the point
$$
\bigl(x=x_0-ay,y,a=2x_0,b=4x_0^2,u=u_0-y(2a^2-b)\bigr)
$$
yielding the solution
$$
u(x,y)=1+\frac{x^2}{1-4y}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

multiply both sides by $\sqrt{U_y}$ to receive:

$\sqrt{U_y}U_x+U_y=0$.

so now you have characteristics:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{U_y}\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=1\\
\frac{dU}{dt}=0$

$y$ gets parametrization linear in $t$

and $U$ is constant on the characteristics.

carry on from here...

Comment: Thanks for everyone's effort but it's a typo in my book it's actually Ux+√u.Uy=0 with U(x,y)=x^2+1

Comment: So it is even simpler.

Comment: How's that ? Can you give me a idea to begin with ?